# Android Grid layout with different weights (span both row and column) [without RecyclerView)

Tags: android, grid, grid-layout

I am trying to have a `Grid layout` which spans in both `row` and `column` based on the item weights.

For example, in a `Grid Container` where the number of columns is 3:
if the first Item has a weight of 2 and rests are 1 it should like this:

[image]

Respectively, if the first item has a weight of 3 and rest 1 it will be:
[image]

And if all weights are 1 it will be simple Grid container.

Can you please suggest a proper way to do it? And preferably without `Recyclerview`

---